# How to delete from list, return the deleted element, and return the "modified" list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

(Newbie alert)

I'm trying to write a function with the following signature, because I couldn't find something similar in the standard libraries:

```
deleteFromList :: (b -> a -> Bool) -> b -> [a] -> (Maybe a, [a])

-- Example 1: Item found in the list, and deleted
deleteFromList (\(id1, name1), (id2, name2) -> id1==id2) 3 [(1, "Jack"), (2, "Jill"), (3, "Joe"), (4, "Jimmy")]
-- returns (Just (3, "Joe"), [(1, "Jack"), (2, "Jill"), (4, "Jimmy")]

-- Example 2: Item not found in list
deleteFromList (\(id1, name1), (id2, name2) -> id1==id2) 5 [(1, "Jack"), (2, "Jill"), (3, "Joe"), (4, "Jimmy")]
-- returns (Nothing, [(1, "Jack"), (2, "Jill"), (3, "Joe"), (4, "Jimmy")]
```

I know this can probably be written by calling `Data.List.find` and `Data.List.deleteBy`, but that would result in two traversals of the list. I want to make my life tougher and do this in just a single traversal.

Comment: so what did you try - "if you want to make your life tougher" try it yourself - i would just write it with `deleteBy` and `find` and worry about performance later. And if it was needed I would use a recursive function with an accmulator i guess.

Comment: `partition (==x)` could be useful.

Comment: The second parameter, of type `b`, doesn't seem useful. You're just forwarding it to the predicate. The same can be achieved with passing a closure as the predicate, and this allows you to use one-parameter predicates (e.g. `null`) directly, without having to invent a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement that function fairly easily with `foldr`, like this:

```
deleteFromList :: (b -> a -> Bool) -> b -> [a] -> (Maybe a, [a])
deleteFromList p target = foldr folder (Nothing, [])
  where
    folder x (Nothing, xs) | p target x = (Just x, xs)
    folder x (m, xs)                    = (m, x : xs)
```

although I'm sure that experienced Haskellers (which I'm not) will be able to come up with a one-liner...

Examples of usage:

```
*Q35115395> deleteFromList (\x y -> x == fst y) 3 [(1, "Jack"), (2, "Jill"), (3, "Joe"), (4, "Jimmy")]
(Just (3,"Joe"),[(1,"Jack"),(2,"Jill"),(4,"Jimmy")])

*Q35115395> deleteFromList (\x y -> x == fst y) 5 [(1, "Jack"), (2, "Jill"), (3, "Joe"), (4, "Jimmy")]
(Nothing,[(1,"Jack"),(2,"Jill"),(3,"Joe"),(4,"Jimmy")])
```

Comment: Is there a more "Monadic" way to write this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive solution:

```
deleteFromList :: (b -> a -> Bool) -> b -> [a] -> (Maybe a, [a])
deleteFromList p b (x: xs) | p b x     = (Just x, xs)
                           | otherwise = let (y, rest) = deleteFromList p b xs in
                                           (y, x: rest)
deleteFromList _ _ [] = (Nothing, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mark Seemann nice job, as Chi has suggested, it's better to improve with partition

```
  Prelude DL> let myFunction x = partition ((==x).(fst))
```

Examples:

```
  Prelude DL> myFunction  1 [(1,2),(2,9)]
  ([(1,2)],[(2,9)])
  Prelude DL> myFunction  5 [(1, "Jack"), (2, "Jill"), (3, "Joe"),(4, "Jimmy")]
  ([],[(1,"Jack"),(2,"Jill"),(3,"Joe"),(4,"Jimmy")])
  Prelude DL> myFunction  3 [(1, "Jack"), (2, "Jill"), (3, "Joe"),(4, "Jimmy")]
  ([(3,"Joe")],[(1,"Jack"),(2,"Jill"),(4,"Jimmy")])
```

This is more general:

```
  Prelude> let myFunction g  x = partition (g .fst)
  Prelude> myFunction (==3) 3 [(1, "Jack"), (2, "Jill"), (3, "Joe"),(4, "Jimmy")]
  ([(3,"Joe")],[(1,"Jack"),(2,"Jill"),(4,"Jimmy")])
```